# Point within a list of latitudes / longitudes

Tags: arrays, apex-code, latitude-longitude

First, I'm coding this in force.com APEX.

I have a google earth KML. In this KML file I have a series of coordinates:

```
<coordinates>
    -73.920776,40.710476,0.000000
    -73.926125,40.705692,0.000000
    -73.933609,40.702782,0.000000
    ...
    ...
    -73.924210,40.714085,0.000000
    -73.922409,40.712849,0.000000
    -73.920776,40.710476,0.000000
</coordinates>
```

What I would like to do is create a array that has all my coordinates and then be able to check if a given lat/lon falls within the coordinates. I've reviewed the points within a polygon but would like to see if there is a simpler approach.

Thanks
Frank

Comment: how about [Convex Hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a relatively small area - which doesn't go over the pole or through the international date line then point in polygon is enough.